# Can I refile an expired patent under my company? I did not file the original though

Tags: patent-applications

In reference to the patent: [US4704935](https://www.google.com/patents/US4704935)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can file and pay fees, BUT you will not get a granted patent.

To Get a Patent you need to satisfy following criteria:-

1. Novelty (i.e. New and not disclosed anywhere in the world)
2. Inventive (i.e. having at least non obvious element with improved efficiency)